# Fail ant build by checking junit report?

Tags: java, ant, junit, build, junit4

I need to cause my build to fail based only on the junit report. Is there a way to do this. I know how to fail the build using haltonfailure in junit tag, but in my build.xml I have access only to the junit report. I am using ant.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
    <fail if="testFail" message="At least one unit test failed"/>
```

in your unit test target.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this:  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html ,

try using `failureproperty="failed.unit.test.property"` inside junit ant task & check if its set & fail when your run completes with :

```
<fail if="failed.unit.test.property" message="Unit tests failed with more custom msg to your test class/suite"/>
```